# Swift: use variable for UITableViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Take this line of code:

`let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! MyCustomTableViewController`

Now I want to replace `MyCustomTableViewController` by a variable, something like this:

`var customTVC: UITableViewController
customTVC = MyCustomTableViewController
let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! customTVC`

The compiler complains with:

> Cannot assign a value of type customTVC.Type to type UITableViewController in coercion

I get the message, but what is the way to do this properly? The obvious point is that the exact sort of subclass can vary and I want to implement that controller reference only once.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the class with a variable name?  That's not allowed by the compiler and it makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Take a look at `typealias`. Search for "typealias" here
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. `customTVC` *is* a variable. It is not a type which is why using `as! customTVC` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can use `typealias`:

```
typealias customTVC = MyCustomTableViewController
let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! customTVC
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) under "Type Aliases".

Comment: Excellent, this was exactly what I was looking for!